# Count anonymous classes in a codebase?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

I know there are tools to count the number of classes i use in my code base, and this is a reasonable software engineering metric (e.g. average lines of code per class).

However i was idly wondering whether there are any tools to count the number of anonymous classes in the code base?

If so would this make an interesting software quality metric? e.g. i would probably be worried if i had more anonymous classes than normal classes though I'm not sure if i should be.

Comment: What do you mean by "code base"? Is that a collection of source code files or a collection of compiled binaries? Or can I use both of them?

Comment: your welcome to use either (or both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the number of anonymous types is a useful metric, whether by itself or when compared with the number of named types. I also don't know about any tools that measure this (that doesn't mean they don't exist, though).

To find out the number of anonymous types in a compiled assembly, you could use these facts about compiled anonymous types:

1. They have the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute
2. Their name starts with `<>f__AnonymousType` (an unspeakable name in C#)
3. They have the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute with `Type="<Anonymous Type>"`

#1 by itself is not enough to identify an anonymous type. And I think you can't rely on #2 or #3, since MS can decide to change them at any time and other compilers, like Mono C#, can use another style. But I think it's the best you can do. Using #1 and #2, you could write a method that does what you want like this:

```
private static int ComputeNumberOfAnonymousTypes(Assembly assembly)
{
    return (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute))
                    && type.Name.StartsWith("<>f__AnonymousType")
            select type)
        .Count();
}
```

If you wanted to find out the number of anonymous files in a bunch of source code files, you would need C# parser. If you are willing to use pre-release software, I think this would be a good job for Roslyn, except it doesn't support anonymous types yet.

Comment: Thanks for this, i just tried out your code, i found that the types marked with CompilerGeneratedAttribute had names like <>c__DisplayClass1b.

Comment: In the code base i tried i found 89/159 (55%) of types were anonymous. this seems quite high no?

Comment: Types with names starting with `<>c__DisplayClass` are not anonymous types, they are closure types, implementation detail of closures.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a tool to do this but I thought it was an interesting opportunity to try out the new [Roslyn CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) which should lend itself well to these kind of questions.

Indeed, it is quite easy to get hold of all the places where anonymous types are created. Just parse your source code files and build a syntax tree out of them. You can then search this tree for nodes which are of type `AnonymousObjectCreationExpression` like so:

```
private static int GetNumberOfAnonymousObjectCreations(string filename)
{
    var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(
                             File.ReadAllText(filename));
    return tree.Root.DescendentNodes()
               .Where(n => n.Kind == SyntaxKind.AnonymousObjectCreationExpression)
               .Count();
}
```

The above code has a minor issue though, and that is that it may give you false positives depending on your viewpoint. Consider for example the following C# file as input:

```
// Part of ToParse.cs
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
var foo = range.Select(i => new { Value = i });
var bar = range.Select(i => new { Value = i });
// This comparison is legal because the compiler considers the 
// two anonymous types to be the same
if (foo.First() == bar.First())
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
```

Since the two anonymous types in the above code has the same properties and are declared in the same assembly, the compiler [considers them to be of the same type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle). My code example above will return 2 for this code which in my opinion should be just 1.

This limitation is easy to overcome by inspecting the anonymous types and ignore types that are equal (same property names of the same type as an already discovered anonymous type). Unfortunately, the current version of the Roslyn CTP doesn't seem to [support that](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/f5adeaf0-49d0-42dc-861b-0f6ffd731825). I tried but the semantic info I got back for the expressions inside the type initializer were `<Error>` and for the actual anonymous type it was `null`.

#### Is this a good metric?

In my opinion it isn't. As with everything else in a programmers toolbox, they are very useful when used under the right circumstances and a simple count (or even comparison with named classes) will tell you pretty much nothing.

In fact, there is only one way to measure code quality:
[image: The only valid measurement of code quality]

Comment: An alternative way to write your `Where()` would be `OfType<AnonymousObjectCreationExpressionSyntax>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Would it make an interesting software quality metric? Probably not. It depends on what the organization is trying to accomplish with the metrics. If the organization views anonymous classes as problematic, then measuring their frequency would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic measures yield simplistic (read misleading) results.

It's said that *quantity has a quality all it's own*. The old Soviet Union and Saddam liked that metric but as history has shown it's a poor indicator of outcome.

Proper software measurement starts with goals. If the goal is to fool a manager into thinking he's managing software quality then SLOC (software lines of code), anonymous method count and the like are fine. They sound cool and allow wildly different conclusions - "you can never go wrong!". But woe betide the software team that has such an ignoramus.

Get a measuring tool and get proper training on it's use.

A gratutious link: [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) is one popular methodology.